# Direction of vectors B and H - magnetic circuit

Tags: magnetics

Does anyone know how to determine the direction of magnetic induction (B in the photo) and the direction of the magnetic field strength (H in the photo)?

Is it taken as arbitrary or is there a rule?

[image]

---

There is no H in photo but it has same direction as B.

Comment: Enis Stranjac - Hi, You posted an "answer", but it was really part of the question. Therefore it should not have been posted in the "Your Answer" box & it has been moved into the question as an edit i.e. as an update instead. *Unless* you are writing the *final conclusion* to your own question, without using any other answers (i.e. unless you have solved the problem yourself, with no further help needed) please don't use the "Your Answer" box below. Instead, you should [edit] the question to add new information or updates etc. Stack Exchange has its own rules - please see the [tour] & [help].

Answer (score 2):

The direction of the magnetic field in a magnetic circuit with a ferromagnetic core is the same as for a simple wire. You can identify the direction using the right hand rule:
[image]

<sub>[source](https://www.reddit.com/r/AskPhysics/comments/f2z19e/how_do_the_principles_of_special_relativity/)</sub>

So once you define the direction of the current, the direction of the magnetic field is also defined.

Answer (score -1):

If the material is not magnitzed (has no internal field), then

\$ B = \mu_0\mu_r H\$

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetism

The magnetic permissibility parameter is dependent on the material which is positive for most materials. This means B and H will be in the same direction.

Comment: This doesn't explain how to determine which direction \$\vec{B}\$ (and \$\vec{H}\$) point, so it doesn't address the question being asked.

Comment: It does if you know what \$\mu\$ is

Comment: \$\mu\$ is a scalar (at least in a first electromagnetics course), so it doesn't convey direction information.

Comment: If it was negative it would flip the magnitude

Comment: I think you are making the question deeper than it is. OP just wants to know, given the direction of the windings, how to determine the direction of \$\vec{B}\$. Their final sentence implies that they already know that \$\vec{B}\$ and \$\vec{H}\$ have the same direction.

Comment: I am answering the first question it was my intention to make the question deeper for a better understanding of EM theory